# Rails, I want to get a list of articles by month, help in tweaking my query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need the output to be like:

```
MONTH YEAR COUNT

Nov 2009 12
Oct 2009 3
Sep 2009 1
...
..
```

I have so far:

```
@articles = Article.count(:group=>'MONTH(created_at)')
```

But this returns:

```
COUNT MONTH_IN_DIGIT_FORM

1     12
32    11
3     10
..
..
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not very portable to another DB (MySQL right now), but this will work:

```
Article.count(:group=>"DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y %b')")
```